# How do I copy command output in vim?

Tags: linux, vim, gvim

For example, if I type '`:pwd`' to get the current working directory, I can select the text in gvim but I can't figure out how to copy it to the clipboard. If I try the same in console vim, I can't even select it with the mouse. I would like this to work with all vim commands, such as `set guifont` to copy the `guifont=Consolas:h10:cANSI` output.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Are you looking for this,

```
:redir @* | set guifont | redir END
```

***:redir*** command redirects the output of a command to a register (@*).
The register @* refers to the clipboard.

For more info on this,

```
:help :redir
```

Comment: didn't work in vim-gtk some clue ?

Comment: @SergioAbreu try `@+` instead of `@*` (well, it works in gvim).

Comment: Didn't work. Had to `:redir @"`, paste in a buffer and copy to clipboard, `"*Y`, from there

Answer (score 18):

Try '`:r !pwd`' to get the current working directory directly in to the GVIM opened file.
You can then copy it to clipboard like you would any other text file contents opened there.

Comment: This is useful, but can I use this with `set guifont` for example?

Comment: No, that is not a shell command so it will not work.

Answer (score 6):

If you're running vim in an xterm, holding the shift key while selecting the text will copy the text to the X equivalent of the clipboard.

Comment: X has two clipboards (at least); your suggestion will place the text in the PRIMARY selection (paste with middle-click) rather than the CLIPBOARD hselection (paste with Ctrl+V in most apps).

Answer (score 6):

For this particular example you could do (note the "!" which makes it go through the shell):

```
:!pwd | xclip
```

or

```
:!pwd | xclip -selection secondary
```

(depending on which X-selection you want).

You might have to install xclip first

```
sudo apt-get install xclip
```

(or equivalent)

Answer (score 0):

You could send to a file and copy it from there:

```sh
SomeCommand > SomeFile.txt
vim SomeFile.txt
```

See [How do I save terminal output to a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file) on AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 0):

`let @*=execute('set guifont')`
will copy the output into the `*` register which corresponds to the clipboard.